# How to set pandas multiindex?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a data frame df which looks like this:

| year | date | Time | observation1 | observation2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2012 | 11-02 | 9:12:00 | 79.373668 | 224 |
| 2012 | 11-02 | 9:13:00 | 130.841316 | 477 |
| 2012 | 11-05 | 9:14:00 | 45.312814 | 835 |
| 2013 | 11-05 | 9:15:00 | 123.776946 | 623 |
| 2013 | 11-05 | 9:16:00 | 79.373668 | 224 |
| 2013 | 11-22 | 9:17:00 | 130.841316 | 477 |
| 2013 | 11-22 | 9:18:00 | 45.312814 | 835 |
| 2014 | 11-01 | 9:19:00 | 123.776946 | 623 |

I would like to use year and date as indexes so that I can retrive rows from a specific year or rows from a specific date given a year. For example, I would like to get data from year 2012. Also, I would like to get data from 2013-11-05. I probably need to use multiindex, but how can I set the multiindex with a dataframe like this?

Comment: As a side note, you might consider a DatetimeIndex instead of a MultiIndex; it allows you to do all the things you want in a very convenient manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make multiindex, use `set_index()` with list of column names

```
df = df.set_index(['year','date'])
```

```
               Time  observation1  observation2
year date                                      
2012 11-02  9:12:00     79.373668           224
     11-02  9:13:00    130.841316           477
     11-05  9:14:00     45.312814           835
2013 11-05  9:15:00    123.776946           623
     11-05  9:16:00     79.373668           224
     11-22  9:17:00    130.841316           477
     11-22  9:18:00     45.312814           835
2014 11-01  9:19:00    123.776946           623
```

But to make the selections you need, the following operations are enough without forming a multiindex

```
print(df[df.year.eq(2012)])
print(df[df.year.eq(2013) & df.date.eq('11-05')])
```

```
   year   date     Time  observation1  observation2
0  2012  11-02  9:12:00     79.373668           224
1  2012  11-02  9:13:00    130.841316           477
2  2012  11-05  9:14:00     45.312814           835

   year   date     Time  observation1  observation2
3  2013  11-05  9:15:00    123.776946           623
4  2013  11-05  9:16:00     79.373668           224
```