# How to group rows of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

| Project | Tasks | Date Completed | Pages |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Task 1 | 2024-01-01 | 12 |
| A | Task 2 | 2024-01-02 | 34 |
| B | Task 1 | 2024-02-01 | 112 |
| B | Task 2 | 2024-02-02 | 314 |

I have to convert this dataframe like this:

|  | Tasks | Date Completed | Pages |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Project |  |  |  |
| A | Task 1 | 2024-01-01 | 12 |
|  | Task 2 | 2024-01-02 | 34 |
| B | Task 1 | 2024-02-01 | 112 |
|  | Task 2 | 2024-02-02 | 314 |

I first tried to use groupby function but it only gives functionality like sum, count etc
But I want the actual values of pages, date, and task

Comment: Not possible directly like that, but you can have a multi-index instead. [How to set pandas multiindex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74918116/how-to-set-pandas-multiindex)